# Visualizing Decision Boundaries of Classifier

Tags: python, classification, visualization

I've built a classifier that correctly classifies six points in R^2 with three labels. However, I'm trying to visualize the decision boundaries that my classifier uses. Is there any easy way to do that with a plt command?

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


 
X = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[-1.3,0.2],[1.7,0.6],[2,3],[0.8,1.4],[0.5,-1],[0.4,-0.3]])).float()

Y = torch.from_numpy(np.array(([0,0,1,1,2,2])))


train_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X, Y)
test_data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X, Y)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=6, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=6, shuffle=True)


myModel = nn.Sequential(*[nn.Linear(2,2), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(2,3)])
myLoss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(myModel.parameters(), lr=0.01)

epoch_loss = []
step_loss = []


for epoch in range(1000):
    running_loss = 0.0
    miniBatch = 0
    for x,y in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        score = myModel0(x)
        loss = myLoss(score, y.type(torch.LongTensor))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.detach().numpy()
        miniBatch += 1
        step_loss.append(loss.detach().item())
        epoch_loss.append(running_loss/len(train_loader))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: No.

Hard answer: Kind of.

It completely depends on how much information are you ready to give up. There is never an easy way to display multidimensional decision boundary.

One option could be to reduce the dimensions of your data using PCA and then run your model.

Here's a little code I wrote awhile back for this, it is not ideal, but this is the best I could figure out.

It shouuuuld work without any modifications.

```py
def decision_plotted(model, X, y, feature_list):
    def color_mapping(x):
        colors = ['blue', 'red', 'purple', 'brown', 'yellow', 'green', 'darkblue', 'magenta']
        return colors[x]

    X_sample = X[feature_list].sample(300)
    y_sample = y[X_sample.index]

    model_plot = clone(model)
    model_plot.fit(X_sample, y_sample)
    y_color = y_sample.map(color_mapping)

    x_grid, y_grid = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.1), np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.1)
    xx_mesh, yy_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid)
    xx, yy = xx_mesh.ravel(), yy_mesh.ravel()
    X_grid = pd.DataFrame([xx, yy]).T

    zz = model_plot.predict(X_grid)
    zz = zz.reshape(xx_mesh.shape)

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.scatter(X_sample.iloc[:, 0], X_sample.iloc[:, 1], color=y_color)
    plt.contourf(xx_mesh, yy_mesh, zz, alpha=0.3)
    plt.xlabel(feature_list[0]), plt.ylabel(feature_list[1]), plt.title('Decision boundary')
    plt.show()
```